# Swift 2: check for type of touch in touchesBegan

Tags: swift2, uitouch

In Swift 2 I have the `touchesBegan` method with `Set<UITouch>`. Now, in the method I would like to check whether it was a tap/touch, a 3D touch..

I tried using `.phase` on the first `UITouch`, but that resulted in nothing. How would I check what kind of touch the user did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check that by looking at `touchesBegan` alone. That method is only called when the user first touches the screen. The system cannot know what will happen after that (if the user lifts the finger again, or if he moves it, or if he presses with force etc.).

You also have to have a look at `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` and check what is happening there.

For example:

1) The touch was a **Tap** if the touches `locationInView` property is more or less the same in `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`. The won't be exactly the same because even if the user just taps the screen the finger moves a tiny bit.

2) The touch was a **Pan** or **Swipe** if the touches `locationInView` property is different in `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.

3) The touch was a **ForceTouch** if the touches 'force' property is larger than a certain amount. This is only visible in `touchesMoved`. In `touchesBegan` the `force` property will always be `0`. Of course `force` will only be available on devices that offer that feature.

If you want to detect a **ForceTouch** yourself you can do it like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
        if touch.force == touch.maximumPossibleForce {
            print("This is a force touch")
        }
    }
}
```

Just be aware that this is called continuously as long as the user presses the screen. If you want to execute some code once when you detect a force touch you have take care that you only execute the code once until `touchesEnded` has been called.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! How would I then go about registering a **ForceTouch** and then act on it?
I don't want to implement `peek and pop` or the `quick actions` but I want my view to respond to a **Tap** or a **ForceTouch** and then do something.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.